# How to define the following regex pattern to this string

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have the following string :

```
[< ="- 2-">649.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">365.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">575.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">299.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">240.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">1.450.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">530.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">785.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">250.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">250.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">656.625< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">393.975< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">675.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">465.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">645.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">399.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">615.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">365.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">398.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">210.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">649.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">615.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">395.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">430.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">565.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">340.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">750.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">495.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">650.000< ="-">€</></>, < ="- 2-">210.000< ="-">€</></>]
```

I am trying to return only the values between those closing tags ">number<".

I have tried :

```
regex =  /[>\d+<]/gi
```

but this also returns the `< 2  >`

Can anyone lend a hand ?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the square brackets.

Comment: Please read a regexp tutorial to learn what `[]` means.

Comment: Grouping is done with `()`, not `[]`.

Comment: Guys, but if that's true why can't I get a match using (>\d+<). I tried this same string on regex101.com and the only way I got a match was with square brackets.